# AutoFac and Lazy<T, TMetadata> w/ attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, autofac

I'm having a problem with the following in Asp.Net Web Apiv2 using AutoFacv3.5.2

I  basically can't get `IEnumerable<Lazy<IFoo, FooAttribute>>` to give me back anything. `IEnumerable<Lazy<IFoo>>` gives me back information, and `IEnumerable<Meta<IFoo>>` give me results.

I don't know what more detail to add, but I can add as much as is necessary.

Example Attribute

```
public class FooStrategyAttribute: Attribute
{
    public FooStrategyAttribute(StrategyType strategyType)
    {
        StrategyType = strategyType;
    }

    public StrategyType StrategyType { get; set; }
}
```

Example: Application of Attribute

```
[FooStrategy(StrategyType.StrategyOne)]
public class Handler: IHandler
{
}
```

Example: Registration of interface:

```
 builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
            .Where(t => t.GetCustomAttributes<FooStrategyAttribute>().Any())
            .WithMetadataFrom<FooStrategyAttribute>()
            .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

Constructor being injected:

```
public Thingy(IEnumerable<Lazy<IHandler, FooStrategyAttribute>> handlers)
{
    this.handlers= handlers;
}
```

Comment: yeah I was trying to anonymize the code and missed that one. let me fix it.

Comment: You try resolve `IFoo` whereas you register `IHandler`. Is it normal ? See https://dotnetfiddle.net/Le4NWR for a working sample

Comment: thanks for the comment, I updated the example appropriately.

Comment: Did you try my code sample ? It works on my machine

Comment: the sample doesn't work on my machine. It is talking about needing Lazy<T> and apparently doesn't recognize Lazy<T, TMetadata> so I'm trying to figure out if its just something I'm not doing correctly w/ dotnetfiddle

Comment: donetfiddle doesn't know the `Lazy<T, TMetadata>` but if you run it on your computer with an empty console application, does it works ?